# Google places uses the wrong input after selecting a result

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm pulling my hair off with Googles places Auto completion.
I have 5 inputs in my page that I would like to bind to google places auto completion.
The page loads fine, and libraries initializes fine all the inputs. 
However, when I click on a result from the autompletion, I realize in the debugger that the wrong input field has been passed to the listener.
Here is how I initialize the inputs :

```
var autocomplete = {};
var autocompletesWraps = ['from', 'destination','publish-dn','publish-an','publish-st'];
function initautocomplete(){
    //Bind the Town input fields to google apis
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    for(var index=0;index<autocompletesWraps.length;index++){
        var name = autocompletesWraps[index];
        if(!document.getElementById(name)) {
                return;
        }
        autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(name), { types: ['geocode'],componentRestrictions: {country: 'nz'} });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[name], 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete[name].getPlace();                
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                var town = place.formatted_address.split(',')[0];
                document.getElementById(name).setAttribute('data-l',latitude);
                document.getElementById(name).setAttribute('data-g',longitude);
                }
        });
    }                       
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&libraries=places&amp;callback=initautocomplete"></script>
```

When I look at the debugger, I see that it's always the last input id of my array autocompletesWraps that gets passed the the listener.

[image]

I am running out of options! If anyone can help that will be great!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Alright, 
I solved this by creating global variables for each of my inputs.
Then populate them one by one during init.
Then everything works fine !